# Nginx how to redirect http to https?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm kind of new in aws services and nginx configuration.
I'm using nginx and my EB instance is a single instance with load balancer at classic mode in front of it.

I have this config file in system:

```
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }

      server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

the machine is behind load-balancer of aws elastic beanstack and EC2 that already configer to make a redirect from 80 to 443 according to aws docs
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

the problem here is that the redirect from http to https is not working, and i am unable to access my website when i come from http to https.

weird scenario when i visited my website http://something.com and then make refresh its make the redirect to https://something.com as i want to but not immediately.
any suggestion how to solve this problem?

*both http and https access work fine but i want that all my clients that access from http redirect them to https.

Comment: @Richard Smith , ohhh sorry i dont update this raw when i did my checked, in my config file its like you said so i dont think this is my problem.
I will update the question

Comment: Try one of these generally recommended redirects instead of using the `$host` variable:
`return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;` or `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;`

Comment: @Bman70 I did deploy with both of your answer and its didn't work

Comment: Where is your server listening for 443 ssl? It redirects but I don't see that it listens to pick up the ssl redirected request. I also don't see a default_server block. Some good examples here (not accepted answer so much, but some of the others):  https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx

Comment: @Bman70  thanks i will look into it , and i wll try those answer or combain some of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this solution and its work
node.js side

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (
    (!req.secure) && (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https') &&
    !req.get('Host').includes('localhost')
  ) {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
  }
  else next();
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.